# hierarchic SQL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical

I have huge table with lot of columns so for simplicity I pick up just the relevant ones.

There are components and moduls. Component can be used as final product but can be built in another component = modul. the same goes for moduls. One modul can be as final product or can be built in another component = modul.

in the real table there just numbers but for better understanding I use the relation component-modul
so for example componentA + componentB = modulAB but componentA can be used as final items as well.
Therfore in the table there 2 columns which identify if the component is using let's say as final item in a plant
assembly_id - means the item is a modul , so must have some components (childs)
in_assembly_id - means this item will be built in another item(s)/modul(s)

as mentioned above item can be final in that case both columns has -1 but at the same time this item can be built in another item(modul) so there is another row with column in_assembly_id <> -1 .in my example componentA

The same goes for items which are already moduls with some components and can be final item or will be built in another item(modul) indicating in the column in_assembly_id.

my goal is to find for particular item the modul item , doesn't matter that the item can be as final product as well

I can use join but that find just one level up.

```
select distinct c.item, c.in_assembly_id, modul, modul_id from items c ,lateral (select a.item modul,a.assembly_id modul_id from items a where a.assembly_id=c.in_assembly_id)
where c.item = 'componentA' and c.in_assembly_id <> -1;

ITEM        IN_ASSEMBLY_ID  MODUL   MODUL_ID
componentA  100             modulAC 100
componentA  50              modulAB 50
```

so to see the whole structure because modulAC is beeing built in modulACDE as well hierarchic query is needed to see the output like this
1.

```
ITEM        IN_ASSEMBLY_ID assembly_id type/level
componentA  -1             50          comp
modulAB     50             -1          modul
componentA  -1             100         comp
modulAC     100            -1          modul
modulAC     100            500         modul
modulACDE   500            -1          modul
```

2. 

the highest modul

```
    ITEM        IN_ASSEMBLY_ID assembly_id type/level
    componentA  -1             50          comp
    modulAB     50             -1          modul
    componentA  -1             100         comp
    modulACDE   500            -1          modul
```

I started with connect by clause but it doesn't work for me, I dont know why I get the modulDE

```
select distinct * from items
connect by nocycle in_assembly_id = prior assembly_id
start with item = 'componentA' and in_assembly_id <> '-1';
```

here is my data

```
create table items (
item_id number,
item varchar2(12),
assembly_id number,
in_assembly_id number
);

insert into items values ( 1 , 'componentA' , -1 , -1 );
insert into items values ( 2 , 'componentA' , -1 , 50 );
insert into items values ( 3 , 'componentB' , -1 , 50 );
insert into items values ( 4 , 'modulAB' , 50 , -1 );
insert into items values ( 5 , 'componentA' , -1 , 100 );
insert into items values ( 6 , 'componentC' , -1 , 100);
insert into items values ( 7 , 'modulAC' , 100 , -1 );
insert into items values ( 7 , 'modulAC' , 100 , 500 );
insert into items values ( 8 , 'componentD' , -1 , 200 );
insert into items values ( 9 , 'componentE' , -1 , 200 );
insert into items values ( 10 , 'modulDE' , 200 , 500 );
insert into items values ( 11 , 'modulACDE' , 500 , -1 );
insert into items values ( 12 , 'componentF' , -1 , -1 );
insert into items values ( 13 , 'componentG' , -1 , -1 );
```

Comment: You aren't getting any rows because of the clause `in_assembly_id <> '-1'`.  Did you mean for it to be `=`? That should give you the output you're looking for

Comment: I am getting rows but not as I expected in the output, with = you will start with componentA as final item and will not get the modul respectivly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my goal is to find for particular item the `modul` item , doesn't matter that the item can be as final product as well

This will get all the `modul` for a `componentA`:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( item_id ) AS root_item_id,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( item ) AS root_item,
       item_id,
       item,
       assembly_id,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( item_id, ',' ) AS path_item_id,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( item, ',' ) AS path_item
FROM   items
WHERE  assembly_id <> -1
START WITH
       item = 'componentA'
AND    ( assembly_id, in_assembly_id ) NOT IN ((-1,-1))
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR in_assembly_id = assembly_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY item, item_id;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ROOT_ITEM_ID | ROOT_ITEM  | ITEM_ID | ITEM      | ASSEMBLY_ID | PATH_ITEM_ID | PATH_ITEM                             
> -----------: | :--------- | ------: | :-------- | ----------: | :----------- | :-------------------------------------
>            2 | componentA |       4 | modulAB   |          50 | ,2,4         | ,componentA,modulAB                   
>            2 | componentA |       7 | modulAC   |         100 | ,2,4,5,7     | ,componentA,modulAB,componentA,modulAC
>            2 | componentA |       7 | modulAC   |         100 | ,2,4,6,7     | ,componentA,modulAB,componentC,modulAC
>            2 | componentA |      10 | modulDE   |         200 | ,2,4,8,10    | ,componentA,modulAB,componentD,modulDE
>            2 | componentA |      10 | modulDE   |         200 | ,2,4,9,10    | ,componentA,modulAB,componentE,modulDE
>            5 | componentA |       7 | modulAC   |         100 | ,5,7         | ,componentA,modulAC                   
>            5 | componentA |      10 | modulDE   |         200 | ,5,7,8,10    | ,componentA,modulAC,componentD,modulDE
>            5 | componentA |      10 | modulDE   |         200 | ,5,7,9,10    | ,componentA,modulAC,componentE,modulDE
>            5 | componentA |       7 | modulAC   |         100 | ,5,7         | ,componentA,modulAC                   
>            5 | componentA |      11 | modulACDE |         500 | ,5,7,11      | ,componentA,modulAC,modulACDE
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=03b24b24e748aafbecdbd439dc888863)*

---

## Update

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( item_id ) AS root_item_id,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( item ) AS root_item,
       item_id,
       item,
       assembly_id,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( item_id, ',' ) AS path_item_id,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( item, ',' ) AS path_item
FROM   items
WHERE  assembly_id > -1
START WITH
       item = 'componentA'
AND    ( assembly_id, in_assembly_id ) NOT IN ((-1,-1))
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR in_assembly_id = assembly_id
AND    assembly_id > -1
ORDER SIBLINGS BY item, item_id;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ROOT_ITEM_ID | ROOT_ITEM  | ITEM_ID | ITEM      | ASSEMBLY_ID | PATH_ITEM_ID | PATH_ITEM                    
> -----------: | :--------- | ------: | :-------- | ----------: | :----------- | :----------------------------
>            2 | componentA |       4 | modulAB   |          50 | ,2,4         | ,componentA,modulAB          
>            5 | componentA |       7 | modulAC   |         100 | ,5,7         | ,componentA,modulAC          
>            5 | componentA |       7 | modulAC   |         100 | ,5,7         | ,componentA,modulAC          
>            5 | componentA |      11 | modulACDE |         500 | ,5,7,11      | ,componentA,modulAC,modulACDE
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8f6fb43258f85488ffc6086bcaa5f3a7)*

Comment: Hi,that the same problem i got, component D and modul DE shouldn't be there, component A goes to modul AB and AC and then modul AC goes in another modul ACDE and that is all I need to get. component A doesn't go in to modul DE so that means modul DE and its components should be in the output

Comment: @PatrikMelichercik The problem you have is with your data model you have too many values of `-1` so everything connects to everything else. You need to work out how to change your data so connect on unique values and not on `-1`.

Comment: I didn't create the table and I can change to table as well therefor I thought the loop can be stop if we hit the item MODUL with value -1 in column in_assembly_id

Comment: @PatrikMelichercik Updated

Comment: MT0, could you explain how it actually works, I don't understand one thing.If you place assembly_id > -1 in the WHERE clause the componentA will be filtered out in the table, how does the query start with componentA if it has assembly_id = -1 ? I tried such query on my real table and I don't understand that this query can find anything without stopping the process and there is  one simple connection of one component to one modul.

Comment: @PatrikMelichercik The hierarchical query will find all the rows of the hierarchy using the `START WITH ... CONNECT BY ....` and then once all the rows have been found then the `WHERE` clause is applied to filter those rows.

Comment: MT0, so that means if the table in from clause is huge with a lot of duplicates in the item,assembly_id,in_assembly_id columns because there are many other columns in my real table. in such case do prefer recursive WITH clause where I can start with my selected itam and join with specific small portion of the huge table?but of course I will not get the same output as you did because the start component will be in the same column as moduls.

Comment: I don't have your tables or data so I do not follow what you are saying; however, you should be able to do everything with a hierarchical query that you can with a recursive sub-query factoring clause (and vice versa).